# how to fetch all github repos url from Jenkins multibranch pipelines

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

is there a way to list or print the github repo that is associated with the multi-branch pipeline. I was able to find a way to get all the multibranch pipelines in a jenkins using the following script via this link https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226941767-Groovy-to-list-all-jobs?page=60 in the Jenkins console and was wondering if there is a way to modify this script and get the list of all repos.
Also please let me know if there is a way to do api call to get this info.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject).each {it ->
    println it.fullName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following elaboration answers both parts of your question. If that's not the case, just let me know.

### Answer for part 1 of your question

To achieve your goal using the ScriptConsole, you can simply use the resulting
`org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject` objects you have already obtained before. A look
at the [JavaDoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-multibranch/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/multibranch/WorkflowMultiBranchProject.html)
tells you that the `item` objects' class implements `jenkins.scm.api.SCMSourceOwner` which enables you to use the `getSCMSources()`
method.

Now that you have a bunch of `SCMSource` objects, you can iterate them and try to find out what they can tell you:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject).each {it ->
  it.getSCMSources().each { item ->
    println item
  }
}
```

In my case the output looks like this:

```
jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMSource{id='7afecbdb-fd8e-4ffe-80ff-f5a22921ee84'}
Result: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject@4ee06837[my-pipeline]]
```

Or like this, when configured using a "GitHub" repo type instead of "Git":

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource{id='774291be-4a81-4558-98e6-0b35c84b1686'}
Result: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject@4ee06837[my-pipeline]]
```

The first line tells us that the actual sub-class of the `SCMSource` class is either a `jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMSource`
which also has a [JavaDoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/git/jenkins/plugins/git/GitSCMSource.html) or a
`org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource` [JavaDoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/github-branch-source/org/jenkinsci/plugins/github_branch_source/GitHubSCMSource.html).
Now the rest is fairly easy, just use the `getRemote` method supported by both types and print (or use) the remote configuration.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject).each {it ->
  it.getSCMSources().each { item ->
    println "${it.name}: ${item.remote}"
  }
}
```

The output is now:

```
my-pipeline: https://github.com/swesteme/jenkins-playground.git
Result: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject@4ee06837[my-pipeline]]
```

### Answer for part two of your question

Disclaimer: I have never used the REST API myself, so I can only give you a *possible* solution, which is probably not
the best approach.

#### Getting the list of jobs as JSON

The first information you need (as in the scripted approach above) is the list of jobs configured in your Jenkins job list.
So to get the list as JSON, run a URL request using: `http://localhost:8080/api/json?pretty=true`

A possible result would look like this:

```json
{
  "_class" : "hudson.model.Hudson",
  "assignedLabels" : [
    {
      "name" : "master"
    }
  ],
  "mode" : "NORMAL",
  "nodeDescription" : "the master Jenkins node",
  "nodeName" : "",
  "numExecutors" : 2,
  "description" : null,
  "jobs" : [
    {
      "_class" : "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject",
      "name" : "my-pipeline",
      "url" : "http://localhost:8080/job/my-pipeline/"
    },
    {
      "_class" : "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
      "name" : "Test-Job",
      "url" : "http://localhost:8080/job/Test-Job/",
      "color" : "blue"
    }
  ],
  "overallLoad" : {
    
  },
  "primaryView" : {
    "_class" : "hudson.model.AllView",
    "name" : "all",
    "url" : "http://localhost:8080/"
  },
  "quietDownReason" : null,
  "quietingDown" : false,
  "slaveAgentPort" : 50000,
  "unlabeledLoad" : {
    "_class" : "jenkins.model.UnlabeledLoadStatistics"
  },
  "url" : "http://localhost:8080/",
  "useCrumbs" : true,
  "useSecurity" : true,
  "views" : [
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.AllView",
      "name" : "all",
      "url" : "http://localhost:8080/"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can now filter the `jobs` array for all jobs where the `_class` property equals `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject`.
In this example that would leave us with the following array (with one element):

```json
[ 
  {
    "_class" : "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject",
    "name" : "my-pipeline",
    "url" : "http://localhost:8080/job/my-pipeline/"
  }
]
```

#### Get the configuration for multibranch jobs

For each of the resulting jobs, you can now query the configuration by calling the job-url, concatenated with `config.xml`: `http://localhost:8080/job/my-pipeline/config.xml`

Unfortunately the result is rather ugly XML (as you would need to parse it using an XML parser library of your choice):

```xml
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject plugin="workflow-multibranch@2.26">
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <properties/>
  <folderViews class="jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProjectViewHolder" plugin="branch-api@2.7.0">
    <owner class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject" reference="../.."/>
  </folderViews>
  <healthMetrics/>
  <icon class="jenkins.branch.MetadataActionFolderIcon" plugin="branch-api@2.7.0">
    <owner class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject" reference="../.."/>
  </icon>
  <orphanedItemStrategy class="com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.DefaultOrphanedItemStrategy" plugin="cloudbees-folder@6.16">
    <pruneDeadBranches>true</pruneDeadBranches>
    <daysToKeep>-1</daysToKeep>
    <numToKeep>-1</numToKeep>
  </orphanedItemStrategy>
  <triggers/>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <sources class="jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchSourceList" plugin="branch-api@2.7.0">
    <data>
      <jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
        <source class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource" plugin="github-branch-source@2.11.3">
          <id>774291be-4a81-4558-98e6-0b35c84b1686</id>
          <apiUri>https://api.github.com</apiUri>
          <repoOwner>swesteme</repoOwner>
          <repository>jenkins-playground</repository>
          <repositoryUrl>https://github.com/swesteme/jenkins-playground.git</repositoryUrl>
          <traits>
            <org.jenkinsci.plugins.github__branch__source.BranchDiscoveryTrait>
              <strategyId>1</strategyId>
            </org.jenkinsci.plugins.github__branch__source.BranchDiscoveryTrait>
            <org.jenkinsci.plugins.github__branch__source.OriginPullRequestDiscoveryTrait>
              <strategyId>1</strategyId>
            </org.jenkinsci.plugins.github__branch__source.OriginPullRequestDiscoveryTrait>
            <org.jenkinsci.plugins.github__branch__source.ForkPullRequestDiscoveryTrait>
              <strategyId>1</strategyId>
              <trust class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.ForkPullRequestDiscoveryTrait$TrustPermission"/>
            </org.jenkinsci.plugins.github__branch__source.ForkPullRequestDiscoveryTrait>
          </traits>
        </source>
        <strategy class="jenkins.branch.DefaultBranchPropertyStrategy">
          <properties class="empty-list"/>
        </strategy>
      </jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
    </data>
    <owner class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject" reference="../.."/>
  </sources>
  <factory class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowBranchProjectFactory">
    <owner class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject" reference="../.."/>
    <scriptPath>Jenkinsfile</scriptPath>
  </factory>
</org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject>
```

**Note:** the output differs depending on whether you have chosen "Git" or "GitHub" SCM provider for your projects.